# Filter entities, then sort on dynamic field

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sorting

I'm trying to FIRST filter a set of products, then order them

```
  (repository.GetAllProducts()
     .Where(x=>x.Naam.Contains("filter")) as ObjectQuery<Product>)
     .FunkyOrder<Product>(sortfield,sortdirection)
```

Using the Extension method:

```
 public  static IEnumerable<T> FunkyOrder<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> input, string fieldname = "Id", string sortdirection = "asc")
        {            
            switch (sortdirection)
            {
                case "dsc":
                case "desc":
                    return input.OrderBy("it." + fieldname + " DESC");
                default:
                    return input.OrderBy("it." + fieldname);

            }
        }
```

(the GetAllProducts() of my Repository returns an IEnumerable

This FunkyOrder method should be working but that  - as ObjectQuery - cast returns NULL

I can only use the FunkyOrder with ObjectQuery because that seems to be the only thing that supports those "it.FieldName" queries.

If I change the - as - notation to A regular cast I get:

```
 Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[MySecretNameSpace.Product]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[MySecretNameSpace.Product]'.
```

Is there any way to make this work or will I be forced to either live with sorting before filtering, or write a giant switch with lambda expressions for my sorting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This actually turned out to be a GIANT headache to try to solve; but in the end, it actually turned out being very easy to accomplish with a bit of hackishness and reflection:

```
public class Program
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SomeClass> sample = new List<SomeClass>
        {
            new SomeClass { Id = 4, Name = "ABC" },
            new SomeClass { Id = 1, Name = "XYZ" },
            new SomeClass { Id = 2, Name = "JKL" }
        };

        var result = sample.OrderByDynamic("Name", OrderDirection.Ascending).ToList();

        result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Id: " + x.Id + " | Name: " + x.Name));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public enum OrderDirection
{
    Ascending,
    Descending
}

public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByDynamic<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string propertyName, OrderDirection direction = OrderDirection.Ascending)
    {
        if(direction == OrderDirection.Ascending)
            return source.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null));
        else
            return source.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(x, null));
    }
}
```

This example worked for me in test situations; I could supply the property name, and specify a sort direction, and it worked great. Simply call like so:

```
yourEnumerable.OrderByDynamic("YourPropertyName");
yourEnumerable.OrderByDynamic("YourPropertyName", OrderDirection.Descending);
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I replaced your OrderDirection with SortDirection from System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Seems like your headache was worth it, it's working fine!

Answer (score 2):

I would change your FunkyOrder method to IEnumerable and implement your dynamic sorting by creating an Expression dynamically like so

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FunkyOrder<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> input, string fieldname = "Id", string sortdirection = "asc")
{
 ParameterExpresssion parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
 Expression property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, fieldname);

 var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(property, parameter)

 if(sortdirection == "asc")
 {
  return input.OrderBy(lambda.Compile());
 }
 else
 {
  return input.OrderByDescending(lambda.Complile());
 }
}
```

You will no longer need to cast to ObjectQuery

Comment: This actually doesn't work. I've reproduced this code exactly, and attempting an expression like `x => x.Id`, where the lambda returns Int32 will result in an invalid conversion to Func<T, object>. Any tips here?

Comment: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Mvision I have updated and tested the answer. Sorry I didnt test it before.

Comment: Do you perhaps know if your lambda.Compile() answer is better performance wise than Tejs accepted solution?

Comment: @Mvision I like using expressions because you can reuse the code with Linq To Entities/SQL. I would guess that using reflection for every object in a long list would be slower, but I haven't done any tests to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) for dynamic filtering and sorting. This small library (only one single source file) contains extension methods of `IQueryable<T>` like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    string predicate, params object[] values)

public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    string ordering, params object[] values)

//...and more like GroupBy, Select
```

Your query on IEnumerable could then be written as:

```
repository.GetAllProducts().AsQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.Naam.Contains("filter"))
    .OrderBy("FieldName desc")
```

The library implements all the necessary reflection code to perform those dynamic queries.

Comment: I don't really want to use dynamic linq just for this simple task!
Thanks a lot anyway!