# Implement Multiple 'Where' condition on dynamic list in which column names are dynamic c# LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of data `List<dynamic>`. Have to apply sorting and multiple filtering on this list. Thing is Sorting column name, filter name as well as the values will be dynamic.

```
     var tempList = (from rec in data
                   select rec)
       .Skip(endrow)
       .Take(RecordsPerPage)
       .ToList();
```

I have tried to implement a built-in predicate, but it didn't work for the dynamic list--maybe I used it in the wrong way. Can anyone suggest a better method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you have `tempList` which you want to sort and filter? but problem - elements in `tempList` is anonymous ?

Comment: Yeh..TempList is dynamic ..also columns which I have to use for filters and sorting also dynamic..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055718/dynamic-filtering-sorting-and-paging-on-generic-list-with-entity-framework

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Filtering and sorting should not be done over a dynamic variable, basically cause its not evaluated until runtime, giving you many problems if it crashes.
"TempList is dynamic ..also columns which I have to use for filters and sorting also dynamic" everything is dynamic? Or lets say POCO/ENTITY X needs a filter and sorting of type B, and POCO/ENTITY Y needs filter and sorting of type C. You have a pattern there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733010/filter-entities-then-sort-on-dynamic-field its a duplicate

Comment: You could consider using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and building filters and sorting as `string`s passed in. Otherwise you would need to build your own interpretor.